# Two different results with contour integration: $I = \int_\mathbb R \frac 1 {(3x-2i)^2} dx $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

This is probably going to be a stupid question ( I don't feel great today) but I can't get around this problem.

$$I = \int_\mathbb R \frac 1 {(3x-2i)^2} dx $$

I thought that using contour integration this was going to be a piece of cake.First note that the integral vanishes on every circle or semicircle in the complex plane.

If we integrate over the positive semicircle, we get $I = 2 \pi i \text{ Res }(f, \frac 23i) = 2\pi i /9$

If we integrate over the negative semicircle, we get $I = 0$ (which is the value wolfram alpha reports).

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is zero.  Your trouble stems from the fact that you have a **double** pole.  The residue at the pole is clearly zero, so the integral is zero.

Comment: Oh my god. You are correct, obviously. Serves me right for relying too much on formulas, **and** for remembering them wrong. I forgot to differentiate after multiplying by $(x-x_0)^2$. Thanks!

Comment: This could also follow from the fact that as function of $\;x\;$ that is an even one, and since the integration interval (the whole real line) is symmetric wrt zero the integral vanishes *if it exists* .